# ¿Cómo puedo configurar fechas en el eje X de un gráfico plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, plotly

Iniciándome en plotly. Importo de Yahoo, cotizaciones de dos valores haciendo:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 

dicc_tickers = {"Apple":'AAPL', "Google":'GOOG'}

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime

def get(tickers, startdate, enddate):
    def data(ticker):
        return (pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo' ))
    datas = map (data, tickers)
    return(pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date']))

startdate = "2016-1-4"
enddate = "2020-10-30"
tickers = dicc_tickers.values()
cotizaciones = get(tickers, datetime.datetime(2006, 10, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1))
datos_yahoo = cotizaciones[['Adj Close']].reset_index().pivot('Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close')
df = datos_yahoo.resample('M').mean()
```

A continuación intento presentar las gráficas de la evolución histórica de estas medias de cotizaciones mensuales. Necesito que en el eje X me presente una escala de fechas, ejecutando el script siguiente:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as ply
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

df = datos_yahoo[["AAPL", "GOOG"]]["2016-1-4":"2020-11-15"].resample('M').mean()

x = df.index.values
y1 = df["AAPL"]
y2 = df["GOOG"]
trace1 = go.Scatter(
   x = x,
   y = y1,
   name = 'AAPL'
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
   x = x,
   y = y2,
   name = 'GOOG',
   yaxis = 'y2'
)
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(
   title = 'Double Y Axis Example',
   yaxis = dict(
      title = 'AAPL',zeroline=True,
      showline = True
   ),
   yaxis2 = dict(
      title = 'GOOG',
      zeroline = True,
      showline = True,
      overlaying = 'y',
      side = 'right'
   )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Para ello, defino la variable x: `x = df.index.values`
Pero no consigo que me presente la escala de fechas en el eje x.
¿Cómo puedo conseguir ésta escala en el gráfico?. Agradeceré vuestras sugerencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es como tienes tu variable `x`. Está en un formato de tiempo que le lleva a `Plotly` a confundirse a la hora de representarlo en el eje de una forma útil.

Voy a ahorrarme el poner todo el código y voy a ir a la parte concreta, que es cuando defines tu variable `x`

```
x = df.index.values

#Esto es lo que tienes que agregar
x = pd.to_datetime(x)
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente usando `pd.to_datetime()`  de `Pandas` nos cambia al formato para que`Plotly` lo interprete adecuadamente.

Lo que hemos hecho ha sido convertir la secuencia temporal de `datetime64` a `Timestamp`

### Nota

No es que te estuviera representando la variable mal, matemáticamente hablando la representación era correcta, lo único que te representaba el eje de abscisas en nanosegundos. Por ello `1.5*10^18`